# CloudTableClient.CreateCloudTableClient threw an exception of type System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-cosmosdb

[image]I am building an Outlook WEB Add-in and added both the Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common and Microsoft Azure.CosmosDB.Table nugets to my project, but the last one shows a warning:

> Package 'Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 1.1.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v.2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

I reference them in the code and try to access my table just like it's shown in the documentation [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-table-dotnet#create-a-database-account) [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-query-table#query-by-using-linq) as follows, but as usual no Microsoft tech runs with first try as it is described:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
...
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = 
CloudStorageAccount.Parse(strAzureCosmosDBConnectionString);
CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

CloudTable cloudTable = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference("users");

TableQuery<UserEntity> tableQuery = new TableQuery<UserEntity>().Where(TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, Account),
                                                                                                         TableOperators.And,
                                                                                                         TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, ID)));

await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(tableQuery, null);
```

I am getting Internal Server Error 500 and the exception of type of type System.IO.FileNotFoundException on this line:

```
CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

cproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common" Version="9.4.0.2-preview" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="2.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.2.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlSerializer" Version="4.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.9.0" />
  <!--<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />-->

</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="wwwroot\myHtmlTemplate.html" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This is the stack trace:

> at Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table.CloudTableClient..ctor(StorageUri storageUri, StorageCredentials credentials, TableConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, Nullable`1 desiredConsistencyLevel)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table.AccountExtensions.CreateCloudTableClient(CloudStorageAccount account) in d:\dbs\sh\aplrc\0506_210442\cmd\18\Product\SDK\Table.net\Lib\Common\Table\Account\AccountExtensions.cs:line 21

Message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Version=1.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: And which file couldn't it find?

Comment: Inspect the exception, it has details.

Comment: I did it, but cannot see anything that helps me resolve the problem. Edited the question

Comment: Perhaps you're missing this nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core`

Comment: No, it's not that. I installed it and I still face the same issue. Also why would I need Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core? I am actually worried about the warning on the Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 1.1.2 nuget. Why is this?

Comment: Are you using the full framework or .net core? and which version?

Comment: Well my project is netcoreapp2.0. It's an Outlook Web Add-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that **Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table (latest version 1.1.2)** does not support .NET Standard. More details are available at https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/344.

However, it is possible to use the Azure Storage SDK (**WindowsAzure.Storage version 9.2.0**).

Below is a sample code to create a new table in CosmosDB/Table account if it does not exist already:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace CosmosDBTableApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ConnectionString = "{CosmosDB/Table Connection String}";
            const string TableName = "{Table Name}";
            CreateTableIfNotExists(ConnectionString, TableName).Wait();
        }

        private static async Task CreateTableIfNotExists(string connectionString, string tableName)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
            await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I found here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9639. My project is .NET Core not Standard

Comment: Do not play with ComsosDb.Table until it is finished. This dll/reference mess cost me whole day of headache. Thanks for clear answere